# Why ternary operator doesn't replace if-else

Tags: c#

I've met a little problem and a knowledge gap

I found using If-Else style is too boilerplate sometimes and wanted to replace it with elvis-operator, for example:

```
Dictionary<string, List<List<int>> VarsWithInfo;
```

want to replace:

```
if (VarsWithInfo.ContainsKey(ruleVar))
    {
        VarsWithInfo[ruleVar] = new List<List<int>> { NestingBlocks };
    }
else
    {
        VarsWithInfo[ruleVar].Add(NestingBlocks);
    }
```

with that:

```
VarsWithInfo.ContainsKey(ruleVar) ?
    VarsWithInfo[ruleVar] = new List<List<int>> { NestingBlocks } :
    VarsWithInfo[ruleVar].Add(NestingBlocks);
```

I know that line with ternar operator is too long in this case, but I want to know the primary reason.
Thank you.

Comment: Note that a ternary is **not** the elvis operator. The elvis operator is the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

Comment: Note, that it usually is better to use a method to avoid duplicate code instead of finding a shorter way of writing the duplicate code

Comment: I think there's an argument to be made that proper object oriented design would replace the `Dictionary<string, List<List<int>>` with a class that handles this behavior so that calling code isn't concerned with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The conditional operator `?:`, commonly known as the ternary conditional operator, evaluates a Boolean expression, and returns the result of evaluating one of two expressions, depending on whether the Boolean expression evaluates to true or false

[From MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

The ternary operator always returns a value. In the expression `x = a ? b : c`, if `a` is `true` then it will assign the value of `b` to `x`, otherwise it will assign the value of `c` to `x`.

Therefore both `b` and `c` need to be expressions which result in a value, and both of those values need to be of the same type.

Neither `VarsWithInfo[ruleVar] = new List<List<int>> { NestingBlocks }` nor `VarsWithInfo[ruleVar].Add(NestingBlocks)` are expressions, and they do not return a value. Therefore they cannot be used in a ternary.

---

I'm assuming your code was *supposed* to be:

```
if (!VarsWithInfo.ContainsKey(ruleVar))
{
    VarsWithInfo[ruleVar] = new List<List<int>> { NestingBlocks };
}
else
{
    VarsWithInfo[ruleVar].Add(NestingBlocks);
}
```

A common way of writing this is:

```
if (!VarsWithInfo.TryGetValue(ruleVar, out var list))
{
    list = new List<List<int>>();
    VarsWithInfo[ruleVar] = list;
}
list.Add(NestingBlocks);
```

This avoids the duplicate dictionary lookup (i.e. calling `VarsWithInfo.ContainsKey(ruleVar)` and then reading from `VarsWithInfo[ruleVar]`).

Comment: Just to extend this correct answer to OP's use case: it only makes sense to replace an `if` with a ternary when the `if` and `else` assign different values to the same variable (and do nothing else)